# how to use jQuery hide/show to toggle multiple div class

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

im trying to find the way around this, im using an inventory system and i need to show/hide a div,
as i was reading i found that if i use div id it only trigger that one for multiple div must use class, here is my original markup,
each time a product is selected it will display the information bellow, i need to keep it hidden and on a bottun clicl let it show the div
which i acomplish but it only works on the 1 row, how will i ned to chaneg my markup and my script to let it show/hide each item individually,
i had made a few changes but not getting anything to work, i didnt post them here because there were too much, please help

```
  <tr id="Mycontent">
  <td>
 <?php
  if($item['is_serialized']==1)
   {
  echo      form_input(array('name'=>'serialnumber','value'=>$item['serialnumber'],'size'=>'   20'));
 }
else
{
 echo form_hidden('serialnumber', '');
  }
?>
</td>

<td>
<?php
if($item['is_serialized']==1)
{
echo $item['quantity'];
echo form_hidden('quantity',$item['quantity']);
  }
else
 {
  echo   'laboratorios' .':'    .$item['custom1'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' .'presentacion '  .':' .$item['custom2'];
   echo form_hidden('laboratorios' .$item['custom1'] . 'presentacion ' .$item['custom2']);
   }
  ?>
 </td>

</tr>
```

here is an exapmle[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEebH.png) and this is my script

```
  function toggleDiv(divId) 
     {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple jsfiddle. Hope this helps you.

```
// Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible andbound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
$(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
    // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box"     elements
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
    $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGbh5/

Comment: i tried it but is not working the url is point at the site example mydomain.com#  i think it will need to point at the script , i tried editing it but no lucky

Comment: Have you visited the link?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to toggle divs with specific ids you will use a dot . instead of #

```
$(".classname")
```

Comment: i tried adding the dot (.) and replace div id with div class it triggers all at the same time, yet another better step and better than how it was but i need it to open one at a time if i have 10 rows, i click 7th row let it only show/hide 7th row the remains the same unless it clicked as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap library for this.

```
<a class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="headingOne<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"></a>
```

Use the div id in `href` and bootstrap `data-toggle="collapse"` in anchor

```
<div id="collapseOne<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
```

If bootstrap is not include in your site use the CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```